# connecting mongoDB to sencha application

Tags: mongodb, sencha-touch, mongoose

Am very new to sencha touch and am currently developing an application that contains list of categories, when a category is tapped it displays a list of category merchants. Am trying to have my database hosted on mongoLAB, having the tables of categories and merchants, my main problem that i couldn't find a way for connecting my application with the MongoDB tables hosted in the mongoLAB and filling my stores with this data, i mean what is the way of connecting my stores in my appliction with the mongoLAB tables giving that i have two stores, categories and merchants store

Answer (score 1):

As you know - "*Proxies are used by stores to handle the loading and saving of model data. There are two types of proxy: client and server. Examples of client proxies include Memory for storing data in the browser's memory and Local Storage which uses the HTML 5 local storage feature when available. Server proxies handle the marshaling of data to a remote server, and examples include Ajax, JsonP, and Rest.*"

Now since remote proxy works on basically AJAX so there must be a HTTP end point to which it can talk (this is unlike Java etc in which you can connect to DB using respective drivers). so basically you have to expose your MongoDB through web services and based on your choice of technology you can create web services easily using Java, Php, Node.js etc